# Instagram API: How to insert all user media in c# asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, instagram-api

I am trying the get all user media from the instagram api and store into  database but how can do that i don't know. i am write the code but using this code just add one media in the database. any one have the idea then please let me know how can do that. here below list the my code.

This is my C# method :

```
    public string makePostFromInstagram()
    {
                    var serializer1 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var nodes1 = serializer1.Deserialize<dynamic>(GetData(strInstagramUserId));
                    foreach (var date in nodes1)
                    {
                        if (date.Key == "data")
                        {
                            string theKey = date.Key;
                            var thisNode = date.Value;
                            int userCount = 0;
                            foreach (var post in thisNode)
                            {
                                if (thisNode[userCount]["username"] == strInstagramUserId)
                                {
                                    id = thisNode[userCount]["id"].ToString();
                                }
                                userCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                        Dictionary<string, object> csObj = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(GetRecentPost(id, accessToken));
                        int length = ((ArrayList)csObj["data"]).Count;
                        var nodes = serializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(GetRecentPost(id, accessToken));
                        foreach (var date in nodes)
                        {
                            if (date.Key == "data")
                            {
                                string theKey = date.Key;
                                var thisNode = date.Value;
                                foreach (var post in thisNode)
                                {
                                    UsersOnInstagram objUserInsta = new UsersOnInstagram();
                                    string result = null;
                                 //here i am add just one image so i want to here add multiple image insert
                                        if (post["type"] == "image")                                           
                                               result = UsersOnInstagram.addInstagramPost(strPtId, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(post["caption"]["text"]), post["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"], UnixTimeStampToDateTime(Convert.ToDouble(post["created_time"])), null, post["type"]);                                                                                                  
                                        else if (post["type"] == "video")                                            
                                                result = objUserInsta.addInstagramPost(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(post["caption"]["text"]), strPtId, post["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"], UnixTimeStampToDateTime(Convert.ToDouble(post["created_time"])), post["videos"]["standard_resolution"]["url"], post["type"]);                           
                                }
                            }
                        }                        
                    Response.End();

    }
```

this is my api method :

```
public static string GetRecentPost(string instagramaccessid, string instagramaccesstoken)
    {
        Double MAX_TIMESTAMP = DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1));
        Double MIN_TIMESTAMP = DateTimeToUnixTimestamp(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2));

        string url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" + instagramaccessid + "/media/recent?access_token=" + instagramaccesstoken + "&min_timestamp=" + MIN_TIMESTAMP + "&maz_timestamp=" + MAX_TIMESTAMP;

        var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string d = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        return d;
    }
```

any one know how can do that please let me know.

Comment: can an instagram post even consist of multiple images? I thought one post = one image.

Comment: no in the one post more than one image is store so i can insert this images in the db

Comment: I've never seen that on the site/app. Can you provide an example URL to a post with multiple images? Or an example of the data received from the API in that situation, so we can see how to traverse it and get these images?